# Identifying paths between nodes on a graph, whilst finding potential loops

Tags: algorithm, graph-algorithm

Lets say I have a graph like the following:
[image: graph]

It is directed, and can also have cycles. If I wanted to find all the possible routes from node 0 to node 9, I have found that I could use a depth-first search algorithm, keeping the list of visited nodes in a collection to prevent the cycles from affecting the algorithm.

However, what I haven't been able to work out is how I can adapt DFS to find which nodes could be passed more than once when travelling between node 0 and node 9.

In the example, we can see that nodes 1, 5, 6, and 3 could be accessed more than once if travelling from 0 to 9, due to the loops. However, I'm not sure how this can be effectively implemented in an algorithm.

I have already tried counting the number of times a node is visited, but this seems to cause the algorithm to iterate infinitely.

How can I find all possible paths between two points in a directed graph, whilst simultaneously finding the points that could be accessed more than once (in a loop) on the way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it separately in linear time.

Let's find strongly connected components and shrink them. Now we've got a DAG.

A node can be passed twice (or more times) iff the size of the component is greater than 2, it's reachable from the source node, and the target node is reachable from it.

If you're fine with exponential time, you can use the following fact: if there a path that contains the given node twice, there is such a path with at most `3n` vertices (let's take a look at its two occurrences. We can cut out all cycle between them. We can also cut out all cycle before and after them).

That is, you can keep using your recursive solution (which never terminates), but always kill a branch of recursion if you've got more than `3n` nodes in the path (there might be an even better bound than `3n`, but this one is easy to prove).

Comment: Hello, thanks for the answer. I don't really follow you when you say "find strongly connected components and shrink them" to get a DAG. How would this be achieved? How do I avoid simply shrinking the entire graph?

Comment: @konsolas You can find them using a standard algorirhm (you can google for it). After that, all vertices in one component are merged into one.

Comment: I've decided to opt for the second solution which seems to be correct and easy to implement, thanks.